# Problem with multiple SEARCH conditions in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I want to extract cell values from Excel table which don't contain certain strings. In this case there are tree substrings "COMP", "CAB" and "GRAN"

The formula which doesn't work is as follows:

```
=IFERROR(IF(OR(SEARCH("COMP";A1);SEARCH("CAB";A1);SEARCH("GRAN";A1));"";A1);A1)
```

And actually I can't understand why is that? Because the same formula with a single condition works just fine:

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("COMP";A1);"";A1);A1)
```

[image: Example of my table]

Comment: =IF(OR(  IFERROR(SEARCH("COMP";A1);0)>0;    IFERROR( SEARCH("CAB";A1); 0)>0;      IFERROR(SEARCH("GRAN";A1);0)>0);"";A1)

Comment: Thank you! This one for me is the most straightforward!

Answer (score 4):

Alternative:

```
=LET(ζ,B2:B8,FILTER(ζ,ISNA(TEXTAFTER(ζ,{"COMP","CAB","GRAN"}))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines using <kbd>FILTER( )</kbd> & <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=LET(
     a,B2:B8,
     s,{"COMP","CAB","GRAN"},
     r,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(s)),
     m,MMULT(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(s,a))),r)=0,
     FILTER(a,m))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Another variation on the `FILTER` function:

```
=FILTER(
    A3:A9,
    BYROW(
        A3:A9,
        LAMBDA(arr,
            AND(NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"COMP", "CAB", "GRAN"}, arr))))
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all!
The code snippet below works best for me, just because it makes the most sense to me :)

```
=IF(OR( IFERROR(SEARCH("COMP";A1);0)>0; IFERROR( SEARCH("CAB";A1); 0)>0; IFERROR(SEARCH("GRAN";A1);0)>0);"";A1)
```

by ΑΓΡΙΑ ΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ